# Bad Disparity Map Dual Lens StereoSGBM OpenCV3 Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, computer-vision, opencv3.1

1. I have trouble calibrating the dual lens camera to get a disparity map. I attached Images and the source code. I've tried a thousand combinations of variables and this is the best I've accomplished with this camera. With other cameras like the Logitech C270 I have not had that problem.
2. Dual Lens Camera http://   i.stack.imgur.com/qKDz2.jpg
   View https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1cYq.jpg
   Disparity Map Result https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1GoC.png

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import cv2

   l_camera = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
   r_camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

   # create windows
   cv2.namedWindow('left_Webcam', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
   cv2.namedWindow('right_Webcam', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
   cv2.namedWindow('disparity', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

   blockSize = 40

   while(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF != ord('q')):
      ret1, left_frame = l_camera.read()
      ret2, right_frame = r_camera.read()

      #our operations on the frame come here
      gray_left = cv2.cvtColor(left_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      gray_right = cv2.cvtColor(right_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      cv2.imshow('left_Webcam', gray_left)
      cv2.imshow('right_Webcam', gray_right)
      stereo = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(minDisparity=1,
          numDisparities=16,
          blockSize=15,
          uniquenessRatio = 10,
          speckleWindowSize = 10,
          speckleRange = 32,
          disp12MaxDiff = 1,
          P1 = 8*3*blockSize**2,
          P2 = 32*3*blockSize**2
       )
       disparity = stereo.compute(gray_left, gray_right)
       disparity = cv2.normalize(disparity, disparity, alpha=0, beta=255,norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
       cv2.imshow('disparity', disparity)

   # When everything done, release the capture
   l_camera.release()
   r_camera.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   ```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to rectify your images first? And why you define an external variable blockSize = 40 with the same identical name of the parameter into stereoSGBM (wich is set equal to 15) ?

Comment: Sorry for other two questions: What if numDisparities is greater of 16 (it must be 16*x, a number like 80 or 96)? How many millimeters is the baseline (distance) between the 2 cameras?